# Sidestep the javac "ambiguous" warning for overloaded methods that only differ by whether parameter lambda is void or non-void

Tags: java, lambda, javac, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am writing an utility class with the following methods (among others):

```
 class FunctionNamingUtils {
    public static <T> Consumer<T> named(String name, Consumer<T> delegate) {
        class NamedConsumer implements Consumer<T> {
            @Override public void accept(T t) { delegate.accept(t); }
            @Override public String toString() { return name; }
        }
        return new NamedConsumer();
    }

    public static <T, R> Function<T, R> named(String name, Function<T, R> delegate) {
        class NamedFunction implements Function<T, R> {
            @Override public R apply(T t) { return delegate.apply(t); }
            @Override public String toString() { return name; }
        }
        return new NamedFunction();
    }
}
```

The compiler complains with:

> Warning: java:
>   named(java.lang.String,java.util.function.Consumer) in ... is
>   potentially ambiguous with
>   named(java.lang.String,java.util.function.Function) in ...

I do get the purpose of the warning - depending on whether the lambda returns a value or void we will go one way or the other, and for single statement lambdas that is hard to see.

The thing is that in this case, that is exactly what we want, and I'd like to use overloading to reduce the cognitive burden of having to remember two method names for the same functionality (I already had to do compromise on that with `namedPredicate` which clashes with boolean functions).

I am looking for any ideas - either about suppressing the warning, or expressing the API in a different way. The focus is on clarity and ease-of-use from the client side.

I only care about Java 8+.

Comment: If you already compromised with namedPredicate anyway, your API would be more consistent if you also used namedFunction and namedConsumer.

Comment: I agree with JB. Of course this is a matter of style, but I often that find that **overloaded** methods tend to **overload** my brain too. For example because of scenarios as this. So my 2 cent would be, too: just use different names for the methods.

Comment: Conciseness also matters though, especially for primitive concepts. Otherwise you end up with names like in Spring Framework (no offence meant, but I don't think it is a good choice for utilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually my understanding of lambdas was incomplete. It turns out that any lambda returning a value can be legally used in position of a void lambda.

Quoting from [errorprone/FunctionalInterfaceClash](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/FunctionalInterfaceClash)

> JLS 15.12.2.1 says that lambdas whose body is a statement expression
>   are compatible with functional interfaces whose function type is
>   void-returning or value returning:
>
> - A lambda expression (§15.27) is potentially compatible with a
>     functional interface type (§9.8) if all of the following are true:
> - The arity of the target type’s function type is the same as the arity
>     of the lambda expression. If the target type’s function type has a
>     void return, then the lambda body is either a statement expression
> - (§14.8) or a void-compatible block (§15.27.2). If the target type’s
>     function type has a (non-void) return type, then the lambda body is
>     either an expression or a value-compatible block (§15.27.2).

In other words, given the implementation above, passing a consumer and a functional lambda would resolve just fine, but then there is an use case where we want to implement a consumer using a lambda that actually returns a value.

For example these two would fail:

```
Functions.named(name, Objects::requireNonNull);
Functions.named(name, it -> Objects.requireNonNull(it));
```

To make it work we need to add explicit statement block like this:

```
Functions.named(name, it -> { Objects.requireNonNull(it); });
```

While this is an edge case, and I could document it in the API, this changes the readability tradeoffs, so now I'm renaming the methods to:

```
Functions.fun(name, delegate)
Functions.con(name, delegate)
Functions.pre(name, delegate)
Functions.sup(name, delegate)
```

While not as nice as having `named` for everything, it is still readable and consistent.

I briefly considered `namedFunction` style names, but given how often these would be used in the codebase, I'd rather have them more concise.